# Update TextView fields in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm parsing weather data in AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method and storing parsed data in strings:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

...
Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
 if (element.getNodeName().equals("station_id")){
    String stationId = element.getTextContent();
   } else if (element.getNodeName().equals("observation_time") ){
    String observationTime = element.getTextContent();
...
```

I have 2 TextViews in my UI. How do I update them in `onPostExecute()` with `stationId` and `observationTime` strings?

Comment: Its Simple, Just make the variables stationId and observationTime Global and use it in PostExecute to set the value of your textviews.

Comment: Change return type of `doInBackground ` to `Element ` and do parsing in `PostExecute ` method

Comment: Thanks, will try to perform parsing in PostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `doInBackground` return type to `Element` from `Void`. Now in `onPostExecute` you will get object of `Element`. Use this object to extract values and set into TextViews.

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Element> {

   TextView textView1, textView2;

   public YourTask (TextView textView1, TextView textView2) {
       this.textView1 = textView1;
       this.textView2 = textView2;
   }

   @Override
   protected Element doInBackground(Void... params) {
      ...
      Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
      return element;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Element element) {
      if (element.getNodeName().equals("station_id")){
         String stationId = element.getTextContent();
         textView1.setText(stationId);
      } else if (element.getNodeName().equals("observation_time") ){
         String observationTime = element.getTextContent();
         textView2.setText(observationTime );
      } 
   }
}
```