# How can I change UI data using an Asynctask class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I want to know what is the best way to use a Asynctask class(`LocationAsyncTask.java`) with an Activity to change UI data(`ListView`).

I have this exception error:

```
Error:(40, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

**EDITED:**

I have this Asynctask class(`LocationAsyncTask.java`):

```
public abstract class LocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{

    public ArrayList<Location> locationList;

    public Context context;

    public LocationAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            //These lines are an example(I will obtain the data via internet)
            Location ejemplo = new Location("Locality1","name","address");
            Location ejemplo2 = new Location("Locality2","name2","address2");
            locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
            locationList.add(ejemplo);
            locationList.add(ejemplo2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {}

}
```

And this is my Activity class:

```
public class LocationNativeActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Location> locationList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LocationAsyncTask myTask = new LocationAsyncTask(this){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                ListView s = (ListView)(findViewById(R.id.lvlocationnative));
                ArrayAdapter<Location> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Location>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationList);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        };

        myTask.execute();

    }

}
```

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvlocationnative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Location class:

```
public class Location {

    private String addressLocality;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Location(String addressLocality,String name, String address) {
        this.addressLocality = addressLocality;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddressLocality() {
        return addressLocality;
    }

    public void setAddressLocality(String addressLocality) {
        this.addressLocality = addressLocality;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.addressLocality; 
    }

}
```

With this code I can not insert data in the Listview, any suggestions?

I check these post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409989/3739382
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193172/3739382

Comment: Use `Handler` .... Or just use `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: in onPostExecute in onPreExecute and in onProgress method you can update your ui.

Comment: can you add Location class in  your question?

Comment: @Sagar yes, added!Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating a new ListView that is not added to anything?

Comment: `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());` really???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of issues with your approach and @Jyoti has just highlighted one of them. You cannot simply use ArrayAdapter as it is with complex object. It won't yield useful results. Instead you need to create CustomAdapter.

1. Create Custom Item view lets say `item_location.xml` under layout folder and put following code:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvaddressLocality"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Address Locality" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Name" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Address" /></LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Create CustomAdapter class as follows:

   ```
   import android.content.Context;    
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;    
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
   import android.view.View;    
   import android.view.ViewGroup;    
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;    
   import android.widget.TextView;            
   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class CustomLocationAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Location> {

       public CustomLocationAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Location> locations) {
           super(context,0, locations);
       }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           // Get the data item for this position
           Location location = getItem(position);
           // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
           if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_location, parent, false);
           }
           // Lookup view for data population
           TextView tvAddressLocality = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvaddressLocality);
           TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
           TextView tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
           // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
           tvAddressLocality.setText(location.getAddressLocality());
           tvName.setText(location.getName());
           tvAddress.setText(location.getAddress());
           // Return the completed view to render on screen
           return convertView;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Update your `LocationAsyncTask` as follows:

   ```
    public class LocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

       private ArrayList<Location> locationList;
       private final WeakReference<ListView> listViewWeakReference;

       private Context context;

       public LocationAsyncTask(ListView listView, Context context) {
           this.listViewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(listView);
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
           try {
               //These lines are an example(I will obtain the data via internet)
               Location ejemplo = new Location("Locality1s", "name", "address");
               Location ejemplo2 = new Location("Locality2", "name2", "address2");
               locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
               locationList.add(ejemplo);
               locationList.add(ejemplo2);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
           super.onPostExecute(o);
           ArrayAdapter<Location> adapter = new CustomLocationAdapter(context, locationList);
           listViewWeakReference.get().setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Update you `LocationNativeActivity.onCreate()` as follows:

   ListView listView = LocationNativeActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.lvlocationnative);

   LocationAsyncTask myTask = new LocationAsyncTask(listView, this);

   myTask.execute();

Comment: Thanks! I change your code and now is workings. I remove a } in your code and I change MainActivity by LocationNativeActivity and now is working.

Comment: @JavierC. No problem. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code:

```
LocationAsyncTask myTask = new LocationAsyncTask(this);
```

as:

```
LocationAsyncTask myTask = new LocationAsyncTask(this){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                  ListView s = (ListView)(findViewById(R.id.lvlocationnative));
                  ArrayAdapter<Location> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Location>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationList);
                  s.setAdapter(adapter);  
            }
};
```

## In your Async task:

- Make the **arrayList as public**
- Use this `onPostExecute()` method:

  ```
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {}
  ```

Comment: Where I need to write your code? in the onCreate() of my activity?thanks

Comment: I removed the onPostExecute  method and changed context and the array list variables to public but I have a problem with the @Override line in the activity.

Comment: I didn't say to remove onpostExecute method. Just remove the lines inside the method . I also update that too

Comment: now I have the problem with the @Override of onPostExecute: "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: can you please post your code, So I can check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167933/discussion-between-javier-c-and-jyoti-jk).